Is Baal teshuvah really greater than a tzadik according to the Mittler rebbe
BH
Hi I heard correct me if I’m wrong that the Mittler Rebbe said that the tzaddik even though the Baal teshuvah is greater than him after his complete process of repentance can still get to a higher level than the Baal Teshuvah through overcoming the challenges of the world. If this is true what is the source of this?

I am not familiar with this statement of the rebbe, but the statement that a baal teshuva is greater is a gemara in brachos 34b, where the explanation among the commentaries is heavily contested. The maharsha https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Berakhot.34b.5  says this is only referring to one who has sinned by thinking to do a sin, but did not actually follow through on the thought. If the original statement is such according to the maharsha, it seems to be itself a source for this.

I saw the same concept in the sefas emes, can't recall where at the moment

I'm no Lubavitcher but I heard from Rabbi Shapiro of Miami who used to write the  Likkutey Sichos for and in collaboration with the seventh Lubavitcher Rebbe that he once said on Makom she’baalei teshuva omdim ein tzadikim gemurim yecholim la’amod bo  - In the place where a baal teshuva,  stands, even  complete Tzadikim  cannot stand  mean what it says- they can not get there even if they try. Afterwards his brother in law, Rabbi Shemaryahu Gururi, challenged him on the truth of his understanding and asked what is based on. The seventh Lubavitcher Rebbe acknowledged that he has no source for his understanding but claimed that his understanding is the simple and correct meaning of what the Gemora is saying.
Being that  neither of them made any reference to  the Mittler Rebbe  having said what he is quoted as saying in the OP it is unlikely that he said it.
(This isn't meant to say it isn't true. Only to question if the Mittler Rebbe is the source)

Challenged on what exactly? What's the alternative understanding?

The alternative understanding is that there are alternate  ways someone who did not do averos can come as close to Hashem as a Baal Teshuva. Rabbi Gurary was of the opinion that saying  the doors of coming so close to Hashem are closed to those who did not do averos, no matter what they effort they make to get there  needs an explicit  source in Chazal to be able to say it.

The straightforward interpretation is found frequently throughout Chabad chassidus and prior to it, as I mentioned in my answer. It certainly wasn't the Rebbe's innovation, though he may have leaned into it. I suspect they were discussing some subtler point in your anecdote.

The original source is Brachos 34b:

Rabbi Abbahu said: In the place where penitents stand, even the
full-fledged righteous do not stand

In the gemara it's brought as a dispute, but the Rambam rules according to the latter view:

A Baal-Teshuvah should not consider himself distant from the level of
the righteous because of the sins and transgressions that he
committed. This is not true. He is beloved and desirable before the
Creator as if he never sinned. Furthermore, he has a great reward for
he has tasted sin and yet, separated himself from it, conquering his
[evil] inclination. Our Sages declared: "In the place where Baalei
Teshuvah stand, even the completely righteous are not able to stand."
The level of Baalei Teshuvah transcends the level of those who never
sinned at all, for they overcome their [evil] inclination more.

Zohar expresses a similar idea:

Happy are the penitent, who in one hour, one day, one moment, get as
close to the Holy One, blessed be He, as most righteous come to the
Holy One, blessed be He, over several years. Abraham did not come into
the supernal days until he was old, as has been explained. Neither did
David, as it is written, "Now King David was old, advanced in years
(lit. 'coming with the days')" (I Kings 1:1). But a penitent comes
right in and cleaves to the Holy One, blessed be He.
Rabbi Yosi said, We learned that the wholly righteous have no
permission to be in that place where the contrite stand. They are
closer to the King than everyone else and draw plenty from above with
a more intent heart and greater force in order to come closer to the
King.

The concept is ubiquitous in chassidus, from Tanya through the Rebbe, to the extent that a common expression (paraphrased from Zohar) is משיח אתא לאתבא צדיקיא בתיובתא, "Moshiach will bring the righteous to repentance." That is, he will impart in them the quality of Teshuvah they normally lack. Since you asked, here's one excerpt (among many) from the Mitteler Rebbe expressing this idea:

כענין צדיקים גמורים שיכולים לעמוד ולהגיע במקום בעלי תשובה כאשר עושים
תשובה דוקא, ואם לאו אינם יכולים לעמוד כלל במקום שבעלי תשובה עומדים, שהוא
בחינת החשך העליון שקדם לאור דתיקון


It's understandable that a baal teshuva could go higher than a tzaddik.  After all, the Mishnah says: "The reward is proportional to the effort" [Avot 5:23].  For example, a baal teshuva who grew up eating bacon-cheeseburgers may miss them terribly and has to work hard to stay away from them, but for one who grew up observant the very thought of them makes him throw up.

The gemara states "b'makom" i.e. only in the matter in which a person made teshuvah.  I.e. his memory of past sins serves as frightening barrier which the tzadik may not have. In other matters ba'al teshuvah is like any other person. But in truth, the tzadik is greater. The question was not about these objective rationale but about the hassidic statement of the Mitteler.

Chassidus has an alternative definition of tzaddik. It's not merely someone with a high mitzvah to sin ratio. It's someone with an inherently better soul ( usually with less capacity for sin.)
So a Baal Teshuva can work hard and turn his life around and perhaps earn more reward but the Tzaddik is on a higher level of spiritually and get closer to God.
Imagine a billionaire showers money on your father. Your father will nevertheless love you more.
Holiness and reward accrued are different things in chassidus.
See the first few pages of the Tanya.
